# CMD Line or MSI install - Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

Trying to install Meshlab.exe from its .exe installer and its easy enough. But would like to install silently.

Is there an MSI installer or any quiet install methods in the default .exe files?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but our IT guy just discovered that you have to run the executable in an admin-level powershell with the /S flag (note, capital S, not lowercase).

E.g.,

.\MeshLab2021.07-windows.exe /S